# Can this sentence be grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, writing, among

Can I say, “He was one of our favorite students among us the teachers”? I want to say that all of us the teachers were counting him as one of our favorites.
Thanks.

Comment: You could use "He was a favorite among all the teachers". You can drop "one of" because you're not saying he's "the" favorite, just "a" favorite. Also, "us the" will sound a bit odd to many ears, although it could be "us, the teachers", with a well placed pause..

Comment: @jimm101 Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

'He was one of our favourite students among us, the teachers'   - sounds better.

Comment: You should explain why it's better.

Comment: @ppr Thanks for your response.